# NVDA is not reading the radio buttons everytime

Tags: lightning-web-components, accessibilty

I have a slds table that contains questions and answers with radio buttons in LWC page.
On using the NVDA screen reader, the radio buttons are reading only for the first time using down arrow key .Rest is not working like if we use up arrow and go to  the previous options like that,

Could someone help me with this?

```html
<template for:each={item.answers} for:item="option" >
                                
    <tr key={option.id} style="border: 0" aria-hidden="true">
        <th scope="row" style="border: 0" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="slds-truncate slds-p-left_x-small inputs-container" role="radiogroup" aria-hidden="true">
                                            
                <input id={option.id} type="radio" onclick={handleRadioClick} data-group="radio-inputs" data-id={option.id} checked={option.isSelected}
                        name={item.id} tabindex="0" role="radio" aria-label={option.label}>
                                            
                    <label for={option.id} aria-hidden="true"> {option.number} = {option.label}</label>
    
            </div>
        </th>
    </tr>
</template>
```

Comment: Does the LWC template you've shared really not have the `<input>` tag closed, or was that just a typo? I'm no expert in accessibility, but I'd imagine that improper html would make it quite difficult for a screen reader to work with.